# Nestjs vercel deployment return cors issue

Tags: node.js, deployment, cors, nestjs, vercel

I deployed my nest js app on vercel.
The thing is I can't make HTTP requests for my nest app.

my vercel.json file.

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [{ "src": "src/main.ts", "use": "@vercel/node" }],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "src/main.ts",
      "methods": [
        "GET",
        "POST",
        "PUT",
        "DELETE",
        "OPTIONS",
        "PATCH"
      ],
      "headers": {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "X-CSRF-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Accept-Version, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Type, Date, X-Api-Version",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true"
      }
    }

  ]
}
```

My main.ts file and Also I try enable CORS other way, but it is not help me.

I try enable CORS,

```
global['fetch'] = require('node-fetch');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
  app.setGlobalPrefix(process.env.API_PREFIX, {
    exclude: ['/'],
  });
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());

  //cors configuration
  app.enableCors({
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'OPTIONS', 'PATCH'],
    credentials: true,
    origin: '*',
  });
```

Please, help me with this.

Comment: You should configure CORS in at most one place. Also, what CORS issue? Your question doesn't share the error message.

Comment: @Zenixo Have you solved it? I tried everything for hours and still have the same issue.

Comment: @Elmatsidis Paul - No. I tried many times and it's not working. Now I host my nest application on Cpanal.If you find a way pls lt me know

Comment: @Zenixo Yes, I nailed it. It works fine now. Honestly, I like very much this hosting provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it is duplicate (I have googled a lot that day), but this stands as workable dev solution for me.

main.ts

```
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.enableCors({
    origin: ['https://YOUR-APP-NAME.vercel.app', 'http://localhost:3000'],
    methods: 'GET, HEAD, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS, PATCH',
    credentials: true,
    allowedHeaders:
      'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authentication, Access-control-allow-credentials, Access-control-allow-headers, Access-control-allow-methods, Access-control-allow-origin, User-Agent, Referer, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Cache-Control, Pragma',
  });
```

vercel.json

```
{
    "version": 2,
    "builds": [
        {
            "src": "dist/main.js",
            "use": "@vercel/node"
        }
    ],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "dist/main.js",
            "methods": [
                "GET",
                "POST",
                "PUT",
                "DELETE",
                "PATCH",
                "OPTIONS"
            ],
            "headers": {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

IMPORTANT: Check if dist vercel's folder is up-to-dated. My main issue was that I did not build again the app, so over and over an old version was persisted there.